"I’m not sure that I’ll go, but I may do." — Why does "may do" sound unnatural here in American English?
the textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 5:

... the use of the verb "do" following an auxiliary verb, as in "% I’m not sure that I’ll go, but I may do" is not found in American English ...

The sign "%" in front of the sentence means this sentence is grammatical in some dialect(s) only.
So we have the sentence which, as I understood, sounds unnatural in American English:
(1) I’m not sure that I’ll go, but I may do.
I'm very interested in why "may do" here is unnatural to some people.
Is there any explanation of it?

my variants:
(2) I’m not sure that I’ll go, but I may.
(3) I’m not sure that I’ll go, but I may go.
Do (2) and (3) become natural in American English or also remain unnatural?

"May" is quite formal these days; other modals less so. Is that the problem?

Since there's so much cultural sharing between UK and America, it wouldn't sound bizarre to American ears or not be understood; it might just sound a bit British.

@AndyBonner as a native Brit the sentence sounds completely normal to me, so that is plausible.

@AndyBonner It sounds really British to me (a Canadian). I've only ever heard North Americans use "do" like that if they lived in the UK.

I'm not native English myself but I would think the most natural way to say this would actually be I’m not sure that I’ll go, but I might. Or does that change the meaning?

@Ivo  That seems identical in meaning, but much less natural to my British ears.

@MikeB that's interesting, because to my British (30 years old, from the South East of England) ears it sounds much more natural! "Might do" is probably more natural for me than either "may do" or "might" though

"may do" is quite BrE but an AmE speaker might also use it.

+1 for "might do" over "may do" (though better than both is simply "might" alone).  NZE native here.  "May" is permissive, "might" is probabilistic.

@Tristan Meanwhile, to my slightly older ears, both sound equally fine but mean different things. “… but I may [do]” sounds like there’s a distinct possibility and you’re quite likely to end up going; whereas “… but I might [do]” sounds like there is a possibility, but it’s remoter and you’re not very likely to end up going. Though I do recognise that this present/past distinction is vanishing and, linguistically, my ears are often at least a generation or two older than the rest of me.

@JanusBahsJacquet I think I agree that that difference in sense is there, but "might do" or "might" are much less marked in that respect than "may do" is

Generally speaking, standard American English and standard British English are extraordinarily similar to each other. In fact they are far, far more like each other than they are to any of the other regional dialects inside their own countries!
However, what the Original Poster has hit upon is a strange and difficult to account for difference between American and British English. An important one for linguists.
Auxiliary DO versus lexical DO
The auxiliary verb DO has no meaning and appears in different constructions which require auxiliaries. Lexical or 'main verb' DO means to perform an action. Its meaning is very vague. A bit like auxiliary DO, main verb DO can substitute for another verb, but only an action-type verb. The auxiliary verb DO, in English, is different in many important ways from the 'lexical verb' or 'main verb' DO:
It can contract with not:

I didn't like cheese.
*I didn't the exam (main verb - ungrammatical)

It can move to the front of a sentence to make it a yes/no question.

Do you like cheese?
*Do you karate? (main verb. - ungrammatical in modern English)

It can appear before a 'main verb' to give it emphasis:

I did finish my homework. (that do can only be the auxiliary. It can't be 'action' DO)

And the lexical verb or 'main verb'  DO needs the auxiliary DO to make a negative:

I didn't do it.
*I not did it (just main verb DO, ungrammatical)
*I did not it. (just main verb DO, ungrammatical)

And it needs auxiliary DO to make a yes/no question:

Do you do karate?
*Do you karate? (just main verb DO, ungrammatical)

An important difference in the grammar between American and British English
Maybe the most important difference between standard US and British  English is that in standard American English, the auxiliary verb DO is always tensed (apart from in imperative sentences like Don't touch that!).
In standard British English, the auxiliary verb can also occur as an untensed (i.e. non-finite) verb. In other words we sometimes see auxiliary DO occurring in sentences as an infinitive, or an -ing form of the verb. Such sentences are completely ungrammatical in standard American English. In standard American the verb DO is missing all its non-finite (i.e. non-tensed) forms. The following examples are both grammatical in British English, but not for most US speakers:

It won't be raining as much as it has been doing.
You needed to have a passport, which I did do.

The Original Poster's example


I’m not sure that I’ll go, but I may do.


The problem here is that the verb after may is difficult to understand as the 'main verb' DO. It would be easier to understand it like that if it has a Direct Object. The following is fine:

I'm not sure that I'll go, but I may do just that.

Without a Direct Object, a listener will probably interpret do as an auxiliary verb in the OP's example, (12). However, because it appears after the modal verb may, this cannot be present tense auxiliary DO, it must be the bare infinitive. And American English doesn't have an infinitive form for the auxiliary verb DO. And that's why (12) is not good for most US English speakers (it's only ok if you can understand DO as 'main verb' DO). However, example (12) is absolutely great for British English speakers like me!
To conclude:
This interesting difference and why it can happen is the subject of many interesting academic studies into English grammar.
In other words: Good question!

You wrote that "I'm not sure that I'll go, but I may do just that" is natural. Does it remain natural if we replace "do just that" with "do it": "I'm not sure that I'll go, but I may do it" ? Thanks.

"I not do it" is ungrammatical for any choice of verb, not restricted to lexical do.  The grammatical version without auxiliary, albeit somewhat archaic, is "I do it not" / (or "I did it not", to match the tense of the example "I did not do it").

@BenVoigt Yes, it's ungrammatical for any lexical verb. It's always somewhat awkward showing all the different ungrammatical ways of trying to do something ungrammatical! (Which impossible sentence is the best one?)

I'm not sure that I'll go, but I may do it" feels awkward as well, because going is an active action, whereas it stands in place of a noun, like "homework".
"I'm not sure that I'll do my homework, but I may do it."
A slightly less active verb "feels" a bit better:
"I'm not sure that I'll take part, but I may do it, for fun." ... It's all kind of shades of gray.
Trying to stay closer to your example, I'd probably say: "I'm not sure that I'll go, but I may". Again, "going" is just too active to feel right as a DO.

"His going was noticed by all." - Again, a bit awkward. "His taking part was noticed by all." - Better, if still oddly passive. If we contort the tense, it also sounds (ironically) slightly more natural. "I'm not sure that I'll be going, but I may do it."

@BrianPeterson Loviii won't get pinged in to read your comments unless you address the comments to them  ;-)

@Loviii I did respond to your question!

@BrianPeterson Interesting – I find it quite the opposite. “His going was noticed by all” is fairly formal, but perfectly natural. “His taking part was noticed by all” is still formal, but also awkward and not very natural.

In American English we'd say "... but I may" or "...but I may do so" or "...but I may go", and in that order of likelihood, though I can't cite any data to back that ranking up. However, in terms of optimality, "but I may" is the most efficient, and "but I may go" is (unnecessarily) repetitive of the verb in the content clause.
P.S. As for why "I may do" sounds odd, my ear wants an object after "do":

Not sure if I'll sing that song at the recital. I may do it.

But only certain  kinds of  actions can be "done".

Not sure if I'll attend.  I may do it. throws an error
Not sure if I'll attend. I may (do so). OK


If we remove "may", then can we use "do" instead of the intransitive "go"? E.g.: "I’m not sure that I’ll go, but my friends always do". Thanks.

Yes, "... but my friends always do (go)" is grammatical there.


Your example: "Not sure if I'll sing that song at the recital. I may do." — As I understood, "I may do" is unnatural to you here, but "I may do it" would be natural. 2) My example: "A: Will you see David today? B: I might do." — Does "I might do" also sound unnatural to you here? Would "I might do it" sound natural? Thanks.


No difference. Equally unnatural with all modals.  Except when acknowledging an instruction in a very curt manner, "Will do".  No explicit subject or object.   Be sure to unplug the saw before attempting to change the blade.  -- Will do.

Yoda: "Do, or do not. There is no try."


As far as I understood from your post, "Not sure if I'll attend. I may do it" is incorrect because the intransitive "attend" can't be replaced with the transitive "do". 2) From Araucaria's answer: "I'm not sure that I'll go, but I may do just that" is correct. Therefore, we can use "do that" but can't use "do it". Could you tell me why? Thanks.


@Lovii I can offer a guess.  Because "just that" is synonymous with "so" but not with  "it".  "Does anyone have the Ace of Spades? "   -- *I have just that."  (ungrammatical)     "You should complete part I before beginning part II. -- I did just that."   That is, "I did so, I did complete part I".

@Loviii While "attend" can be intransitive, I would personally assume the sentence is really "Not sure if I'll attend (the event)." rather than "Not sure if I'll attend (to something)."

Even if the sentence were "Not sure if I'll attend the meeting", it would be marginal at best to add "I may do it".  My ear still expects "do so" there, or "may", or "may attend".

"May do" isn't directly parallel to any part of "I'm not sure that I'll go": you can't expand or substitute it to get a full expression like "*I may do go."
Generally, "do" can become an auxiliary in front of any verb, like "goes"/"does go", making it possible in a variety of tags or fragments regardless of the main verb. But "may do" already has an auxiliary verb, so it loses that ability.
"May" and "may go" are both valid alternatives that employ or allow the correct main verb, and both sound natural.
As you mention, this isn't an absolute rule of English. I'm not a native speaker of a dialect that permits "may do" (which strikes me as British in particular), so the alternative rules that make it valid are left as an exercise to the reader.

Personally, I think it's American rather than British English that extends the potential scope of do like this. Similar to the way some AmE speakers ask "What do you got?" rather than "What have you got?" I realize that to some extent that's a result of rapid speech reducing the entire auxiliary verb to a schwa, and downgrading the final /t/ of what to /d/, where BrE might reduce it to a glottal stop, but I doubt all native AmE speakers are aware the reduced auxiliary was originally have.

"A: Will you see David today? B: I might do." — As far as I know, "I might do" is correct here. But by your logic, it's supposed to be incorrect because, after doing the parallelism, we get "I might do see" which is incorrect.

@Loviii: You misunderstand the construction. As pointed out elsewhere, it's truncated from a notional "I might do so" (or "I might do so" or  "I might do what you said", etc.).

@FumbleFingers "What do you got?" is synonymous with "What do you have?" That is,  got is a lexical verb there with do-support for the interrogative. It's like "What do you think?"  In your "What have you got", how do you parse "have" and "got"? Isn't "have" auxiliary there?

@TimR: I've never encountered that parsing before. It certainly wouldn't work for "Whatta you done?", often enunciated with /d/ instead of /t/. But we all have our inexplicable foibles and "reductions too far", innit?

@FumbleFingers Your "whatta you done" examples are all heavy written accents, which I wouldn't take as strong evidence that anyone actually talks that way, let alone with mainstream acceptance. "What've you done" may occasionally be slurred to the point of dropping the /v/, but I think you'd be hard-pressed to find anyone who genuinely says "what do you done".

@Loviii "I might do" would not be a natural answer to "Will you see David today?" in my dialect of American English, for the same reasons above. I don't think there's any relevant difference between the two examples.

@the-baby-is-you: "What do you got?", which is what FumbleFingers is responding to in TimR's preceding comment, is a faux-legitimate spelling of "whadda you got?" (phonetically), which is a simplified pronunciation of "what've you got?" (the distinction between got/done is irrelevant here). "What do you got?" is not authentic English, it's trying to represent a spoken accent using the nearest legible English words; not because they're grammatically correct but because they sound similar. You're making the same point as FumbleFingers, in response to their improved example of what TimR said.

@Flater Except they're not equivalent. TimR is right, "what do you got" is often used legitimately, a point muddied by bringing up the similar-sounding but nonsensical "whatta you done".

Or indeed worse,but the deep south creoles are cool anyway, I once made a lady there aware that her shoelaces were loose. She replied that they indeed "did gone went unmade" which I thought was an impressive collection of verbs for the situation.

In the Pogo comic strip, Walt Kelly (who had a marvelous ear for parodying dialect) had a pair of characters debating whether the correct phrasing was "ooh, an octopots is got me", "ooh, an octopots done got me", or "ooh, an octopots is done got Albert!"  (agreed to be either safer or more generous, depending.) I suspect that there are in fact "correct" dialectical usages for these concatenations that map to formal tenses (would "is done" be present perfect or past perfect?) but I Am Not A Linguist.

@the-baby-is-you Legitimate doesn't mean grammatical though. "What do you got?" is a bastardization of a shortening of the actually grammatical usage. I agree that colloquial/idiomatic usage can be justified even when not grammatic, but that's not the point being made. TimR claims that the "do" in "What do you got" and "what do you think" is the same, and this part I disagree with. "do you got" is not grammatical in the same sense that "do you think" is. The only reason "What do you got?" is accepted as usage is because it is phonetically near identical to an (accented) "what've you got?".
